# A female lead who comes back to the past

Tags: story-identification, manga

After the female lead gets betrayed, she would wake up in the past before she met her husband. She takes care of her husband and son unlike before she gets betrayed. The husband have like another personality. The latest thing I know about it is that the female lead promises herself to revenge her mother due to her liver being experimenter on.

Comment: Can you confirm "liver" isn't a typo of life or anything else, and you're specifically referring to experiments on the human organ?

Comment: Its not a typo, a liver was shown.

Comment: That's at least a unique detail. Do you remember about when you read this? Was it in black and white or full color? Do you have any idea what the source language was, e.g. was this a Japanese manga, Korean Manhwa, or Chinese Manhua?

Comment: Full color and it is a korean Manhwa, though I'm not sure if it is

Answer (score 3):

I finally found it! It's ***[Never Let Go of My Ex-Husband](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/never-let-go-of-my-ex-husband)***.

> Shi Weiyi, the second elder daughter of the Shi family, abandoned her husband and stepson and ran away with another wicked man, but was in the end murdered by the wicked man and her half sister. When she came to her senses again, she found herself reincarnated and had a vague memory of being locked up by a silver-masked man. Who is this silver-mask? How was she murdered in her previous life? Why couldn't she like her stepson and who is his mother? In this life, she will figure these all out and seek her own vengence.

Comment: Glad you found it. We'd be grateful if you'd mark your answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), which you can do by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons on the left side of the answer. It's this site's way of formally indicating that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction.